# Introduction to Nihilism

Tags: reference-request, nihilism

What are some good basic texts to study on Nihilism on your own. I am interested in knowing philosophy of Nihilism.

Answer (score 4):

Nihilism is not a single philosophy. “Nihilism” is used to describe any position in philosophy that supports there being nothing of a certain kind. It is used to refer to the views, among others, that:

- nothing exists, a position in ontology (see [this article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/) in the SEP)
- no compound objects exist, a position in mereology (see [this article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ordinary-objects/#EliCon) in the SEP)
- nothing is morally wrong, a position in ethics (see [this article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/skepticism-moral/#SkeHyp) in the SEP)
- there is no meaning to life (see [this article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/life-meaning/#Nih) in the SEP)

If it is the last of these you are interested in, I recommend starting with Thomas Nagel's essay “The Absurd” in the *Journal of Philosophy* 68: 716–27, and reprinted in his book *The View from Nowhere.* You can probably find it also online. Similarly introductory is Simon Blackburn's excellent little book *Being Good*, in which Chapter 10 and other chapters discuss the meaningfulness or meaninglessness of life, and what kind of reasons there might be that life is not meaningless. For a classic discussion of meaninglessness which is less straightforward to read and more tied to concerns about the supernatural, see Albert Camus's *The Myth of Sisyphus*.